# Book about Dragons Ending (Turning to stone)

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I read a book once that was some variation on a fantasy setting with magic and such, but the one factor I recall about it was that the dragons in this world could End - essentially, they turned into stone or some such thing and were impervious, and I think at one point a dragon Ends to keep some supernatural being(s) trapped in a box.  The dragon wrapped itself around the being and then Ended.

I will try to think of more details.

EDIT: I had a discussion with my friend. He remembered some of these things, and this is the sum, between us. As a disclaimer, I remember some of this, but I wouldn't have guaranteed it was from the same story. HE said that it was, with surety.

- The story is set in high fantasy
- A main character (The main?) is a female.
- She is travelling with a group of people (mostly men, number unknown)
- One of the men is a huge guy who is a walking arsenal of weapons. At one point she needs to be weapons trained and is given one of the swords he carries.
- In this world there are magical swords, one for each element of magic. Apparently this man carries one of them, largely by accident.
- The prison that is resealed by the dragon Ending is a prison of these evil spirit beings. The beings possess people, and when the person is killed they light into a new body of one of those nearby, unless they are stopped through... some ritual, spell, etc.
- One of them ends up inside the body of a semi invincible golem, posing the problem of an invincible nefarious spirit inside a mostly invincible body.

I hope that these additions help, and do not pose more confusion, or are not mis-remembered from the wrong story. Thanks.

Comment: Does ["The Beginning of an End"](http://books.google.ca/books?id=2F9dt6YBKecC&pg=PA21&dq=dragon+turning+into+stone&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n16xT-_2K47OiALEqfyDBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=dragon%20turning%20into%20stone&f=false) by Cara L Bolth ring a bell?

Comment: @Darius It doesn't, but thank you for the response.

Comment: The dragons remind me of the end of Robin Hobb's Assassins Quest, but the other details don't fit.

Comment: @Darius, I think you're the first reference I've found to my book on a forum discussion. Cheers for the shout out and please, I have some questions. You ask if my book 'rings any bells'. I'm very curious to know if it is known, or if you know of others who read or bought it. Would love to know what you think of the story. I since rewrote it and am currently seeking traditional publication. It's grown a lot from those 77 pages. Cara

Comment: @CaraBolth I wish I could say I read your entire novel. I only ready some parts of it. I thought that dragons turning into stone was quiet interesting plot. In your latest edition, do you expand more on that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this might be Prophecy by Elizabeth Haydon http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/515587.Prophecy The Character Grunthar carries many weapons on his back and tends to collect different one. It is high fantasy and the lead is a female. She travel with two or three men. And there is a dragon in this one. It's the second book in a trilogy. I've only read the first two so I'll have to dig a little to see if it fits with the turning to stone part. Or hopefully you'll remember it. Also here is a link to the wiki on the author it's the Rhapsody Series http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Haydon

Here is an excerpt:

> Do you like copper, Pretty? It is really nothing more than the spent blood of dragons of my kind, just as the vein of gold that formed your locket once ran in the veins of a golden dragon. Emeralds, rubies, sapphires--nothing more than the clotted life's blood of ancient dragons of various sub-races, various colors. It is what we leave behind in the hope that Time will maintain our memory, but it never does. Instead, it serves only to adorn the breasts of women and the empty heads of kings.

Comment: That. Thank you very much, that series was the one we were trying to identify. The only thing we can't remember is the actual dragon turning part, but every other detail fits and there is indeed a Vault with the spirit creatures and etc. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Glad that was it! I'm not clearly remembering the dragon turning to stone either but I didn't finish the second book or the third so it might be in them. I do remember the walking arsenal of weapons though that's what triggered it for me.

Comment: The dragon turing to stone was at the end of the fourth book (or, 1st book of the second trilogy), when a friendly dragon (whose name I forgot) saves Rhapsody's life by encasing her with it's body, and turning into living stone.